# Where are GWT Guava gwt.xml definition files?

Tags: gwt, guava

No, this is not asking how to get guava working in GWT, as I have got it working.

My questions is, when I perform the inherit

```
<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>
```

I expect to find a file Collect.gwt.xml within a namespace com.google.common.collect.

Nope, I searched high and low and the file is not found anywhere (and yet my GWT compile works like a ... charm) . And I cannot find the source files anywhere. There could be one of few reasons:

1. The files are hidden in a jar and I failed to search inside jars. Tell me which jars.
2. GWT compiler provides special treatment to guava. No jackets required.
3. But, does GWT compiler spontaneously redirects itself somewhere to look for the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

guava-gwt source code v.10.0.1: [Collect.gwt.xml](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-gwt/src/com/google/common/collect/Collect.gwt.xml?name=v10.0.1)

Comment: No, I am not looking for the guava source. Thank you very much. I can get it thro maven. I am asking about how is it that GWT compiler does not complain of no source found. The question is ... where is the source code as far as visibility to GWT compiler is concerned.

Comment: this is the source code for guava-gwt, and shows you that Collect.gwt.xml is indeed where you expect it to be

Answer (score 6):

The source as well as the .gwt.xml files are located in the guava-gwt.jar file.